# How can one improve Apache NetBeans 9.0 installation instruction?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-9

The official installation instruction for `Apache NetBeans 9.0` not clear. If you go to the installation [link](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) and look through the text you would see "Mac OSX" being mentioned and and no mention of "Windows". Reader should be told that "from a ZIP Archive" means "for Windows"!

I know that `NetBeans` is an open source project, but is there a way to get to the source code of the installation instruction? What should I know before making a change?

Comment: [1] _"from a ZIP Archive" means "for Windows"_ => Since zip files can be used on any platform, they probably decided that Windows (or MacOS or Linux) is strongly implied. The NB 9 installation page also recently added a YouTube link to a video titled [Get Started with NetBeans from a ZIP Archive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am-7aa2hYgc), though the demo is shown using macOS, not Windows. [2] _"What should I know before making a change"_ => Installing a new release has no impact on any existing NetBeans installation(s). It is unfortunate that the release note does not make that clear.

Comment: I want to improve installation instruction, that is the goal of the question. Improvement of the installation instruction is the change I want to make. How can I do it?

Comment: OK, but in that case isn't your question effectively seeking opinion based answers, which would be off topic for SO? As a related matter you might be interested in [CoolBeans](http://coolbeans.xyz/): _"CoolBeans is an IDE distribution. It packages the best there is in the Apache NetBeans ecosystem, polishes it, fixes minor annoyances and serves them to you in a clean bundle."_.

Comment: No, I don't want opinions, I want resources and official project rules to follow. I don't really know what is needed to make a change, but I'm sure that opinions are definitely not needed to make a change. CoolBeans is maybe what I needed. I'm going to have a closer look at it. Thank you.

Comment: Just FYI, [NetBeans 10.0 was released today](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html).